# Using IdentityServer 4 without specifying clients

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid

Is it possible to use IdentityServer 4 without knowing about the clients? I'm trying to set up an environment where everyone in a class can build their own application, that uses the same AuthServer to validate their LDAP credentials.

Every resource I've looked at specifies clients that can use the api, but since I can't register every single student I'm looking for some kind of "public" client that everyone can use. The IdentityServer should just make it a little easier for the students so they don't have to query the ldap on their own.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have many clients or many users? Do you have a lot of clients?

Comment: Why not give the same clientID to all the students?